# View Records in sql base on the closest date and time

Tags: php, mysql, select, timestamp, datediff

Please help me view the records based on **closest date and time.**

I can only display the closest **DATE**, i dont know how to display it with time.

here's my code

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_schedules WHERE schedule_time > NOW() 
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(schedule_time , NOW())) ASC
```

the `schedule_time` is in TimeStamp format in mysql.

help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the timestamps to numeric format, and subtract them.

```
ORDER BY ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(schedule_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) ASC
```